# How to plot the fitting curves in a GAM regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, gam

I am trying to fit a GAM model as follows:

```
model <- gam(`output` ~ s(`var 1`) + s(`var 2`), data = mydata)
```

Where `mydata` is a `data.frame` containing the data I need with columns: `output`, `var 1` and `var 2`.

When I run the command I get this warning:

```
Warning message:
In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  non-list contrasts argument ignored
```

Which I have no idea what it means. However I can see that the model is fit as `summary(model)` returns stuff.

Now I would like to plot the fitting curves for:

- `output` against `var 1`
- `output` against `var 2`

How?

---

#### Attempt I

I have tried to:

```
plot(model)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in parse(text = evars) : <text>:1:8: unexpected symbol
1: var 1
```

Comment: are you sure it is not the `gam` model that errors rather than the plot method?  (e.g. mtcars$`var 1`= mtcars$wt ; gam(mpg ~ s(`var 1`), data=mtcars)). But I think you would find it easier if you used names that are easier for r to parse -- see `?make.names`

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the names. `lm` accepts the syntax of names enclosed in backticks. `gam` does not. In the end, I changed the data frame to allow this:

```
model <- gam(y ~ s(x) + s(w), data = mydata)
```

And then the plotting worked.